# How to make slider move percent by percent when I click "Play"?

Tags: javascript, audio, slider, audio-player

There are compositions with different duration and for them slider should move with different speed. For example, for one case, there is 3 seconds in 1 percent, in other case there is 5 seconds and so on. How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're making a video player, correct?

This will set a playhead element according to the elapsed time.

```
var playHeadPosition = videoEl.currentTime / videoEl.duration;
playheadEl.style.left = playHeadPosition + "%";
```